# Is it possible to have a recursive solution for this Divide and Conquer problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, divide-and-conquer

I have written a code which simulate a lottery by calculating, amongst a list of intervals of consecutive integers, the sum of the number of intervals in which a given number is present. Since this can be described as a "Divide and Conquer" algorithm, I would like to know if it is possible to draw a recursive solution for it.

```
def lottery_sort(segments, bets):
    segments = [(segments[2*i], segments[2*i + 1])
                        for i in range(len(segments) // 2)]

    s_open = [i[0] for i in segments]
    s_open.sort()
    s_close = [i[1] for i in segments]
    s_close.sort()

    bets = sorted([bet for bet in bets])

    res = []
    count = 0
    o = 0
    c = 0
    size = len(segments)
    for bet in bets:
        while o < size and s_open[o] <= bet:
            o += 1
            count += 1
        while c < size and s_close[c] < bet:
            c += 1
            count -= 1
        res.append(count)

    return res
```

Comment: Can you talk a bit more about what the code is supposed to do? How is it related to lotteries? How would you use the function? Can you show some example input and desired output?

Comment: It is related to a lottery in the sense that a participant’s payoff is proportional to the number of ranges that contain the participant’s number minus the number of ranges that does not contain it. For example having intervals "[(0,5), (7,10)]" and "[1, 6, 11]" as bets, the output would be "[1, 0, 0]" because 1 is present in one interval, 6 and 11 in no one.
Having the input just as integer, the function convert the ones representing the segments in a list of tuples, and the input bets in a list as well.